Powerbiclient API is not working in Jupyter notebbok
I am trying to connect power bi reports which are hosted on power bi service. Below is the code for the same. Device flow authentication successfully completed, but it is giving me below error.
# Import Report class
from powerbiclient import Report

# Import DeviceCodeLoginAuthentication class to authenticate to Power BI
from powerbiclient.authentication import DeviceCodeLoginAuthentication

# Initiate device authentication
device_auth = DeviceCodeLoginAuthentication() # tenant_id is an optional argument

# Set workspace Id and report Id
group_id="my_worspace_id"
report_id="my_report_id"

# Create an instance of Power BI Report
# Use auth object
report = Report(group_id=group_id, report_id=report_id, auth=device_auth,Verify=False)

Error Details:
Performing device flow authentication. Please follow the instructions below.
To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code XXXXXX to authenticate.
Device flow authentication successfully completed.
You are now logged in .
The result should be passed only to trusted code in your notebook.
Exception: Could not get embed URL: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.powerbi.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1.0/myorg/groups/group_id/reports/report_id (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1000)')))
